# Create column in DataFrame for each row in other DataFrame and compute values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, performance

I have a DataFrame called `player`:

```
player_df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,3), columns=['x','y','more_cols'])

_____________________________________________________________________________
player_df:
          x         y  more_cols
0  0.352673  0.479360   0.638508
1  0.764669  0.326961   0.778483
2  0.805774  0.911662   0.316030
3  0.114446  0.185147   0.318742
4  0.714803  0.646525   0.084143
5  0.061614  0.837432   0.886669
6  0.179777  0.519559   0.446562
7  0.615326  0.886046   0.581127
8  0.597375  0.196619   0.310331
9  0.670061  0.471363   0.313047
```

a second DataFrame called `checkpoints_df`:

```
checkpoints_df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(4,2), columns=['x','y'])
checkpoints_df['checkpoint_name'] = ['Alpha', 'Hotel', 'Indigo', 'Papa']
_____________________________________________________________________________
checkpoints_df: 
          x         y checkpoint_names
0  0.616945  0.804442            Alpha
1  0.402007  0.556274            Hotel
2  0.478351  0.443920           Indigo
3  0.075494  0.803561             Papa
```

and a function `distance(x1,y1,x2,y2)` that calculates the euclidean distance between 2 points, or a list of points and a point (x1 and y1 can be lists).

Goal: I want to add a column to 'player_df' for each checkpoint name in 'checkpoints_df['checkpoint_name']', and fill the column with the distance of the player to that checkpoint (this is a mockup problem, the real problem could have a lot of 'checkpoints')

So far I've tried many things, but settled on a solution that uses `.iterrows()`, however this could be slow if there are many checkpoints. This is what I use right now:

```
for _, row in checkpoints_df.iterrows():
        player_df[row['name']] = distance(player_df['x'], player_df['y'], row['x'], row['y'])
```

I've tried using `.apply()` but couldn't create columns with this. Is there a way to do this without iterating over the second dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `distance` function is vectorized, you can do:

```
import numpy as np

def distance(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    return np.sqrt((x2-x1)**2+(y2-y1)**2)

tmp = checkpoints_df.set_index('checkpoint_name')

for c in checkpoints_df.index:
    player_df[c] = distance(player_df['x'], player_df['y'],
                            tmp.loc[c, 'x'], tmp.loc[c, 'y'])
```

Or, fully vectorized:

```
player_df[checkpoints_df['checkpoint_name']] = distance(
    player_df['x'].to_numpy()[:,None], player_df['y'].to_numpy()[:,None],
    checkpoints_df['x'].to_numpy()[None], checkpoints_df['y'].to_numpy()[None]
)
```

Output:

```
          x         y  more_cols     Alpha     Hotel    Indigo      Papa
0  0.548814  0.715189   0.602763  0.290325  0.173562  0.538927  0.116871
1  0.544883  0.423655   0.645894  0.448875  0.169807  0.560716  0.204632
2  0.437587  0.891773   0.963663  0.209178  0.323871  0.500542  0.325561
3  0.383442  0.791725   0.528895  0.120166  0.234831  0.404077  0.287810
4  0.568045  0.925597   0.071036  0.339141  0.374280  0.629699  0.311790
5  0.087129  0.020218   0.832620  0.774609  0.660846  0.601313  0.794770
6  0.778157  0.870012   0.978618  0.522455  0.441177  0.800208  0.302696
7  0.799159  0.461479   0.780529  0.619367  0.359296  0.795839  0.243226
8  0.118274  0.639921   0.143353  0.198590  0.345356  0.101950  0.494356
9  0.944669  0.521848   0.414662  0.725433  0.490735  0.930821  0.345899
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This works well in Pandas. I didn't realize casting a whole column to numpy was "good practise" so to speak (as it feel hacky). Is it possible to have such a solution in PySpark? As in, casting a whole column to numpy doesn't work in PySpark.

Comment: I couldn't say for PySpark, but for pandas/numpy this is not hacky at all, you should always try to vectorize your operations. `iterrows` is the frowned upon approach ;)

Comment: > iterrows is the frowned upon approach ;) <

Yeah I thought so, hence the question haha. Good to know for the future as well!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a concise way to leverage numpy broadcasting to create the desired output:

```python
def distance(x1,y1,x2,y2):
    return np.sqrt((x1-x2)**2+(y1-y2)**2)

df1, df2 = player_df, checkpoints_df
df1[df2.checkpoint_name] = distance(*[df.to_numpy() for df in 
    [df1[[c]] for c in 'xy'] + 
    [df2[[c]].T for c in 'xy']])
```

Sample Input:

```
   x  y  more_cols
0  0  0        0.0
1  0  1        0.5
2  0  2        1.0
3  0  3        1.5
4  0  4        2.0
5  0  5        2.5
6  0  6        3.0
7  0  7        3.5
8  0  8        4.0
9  0  9        4.5
   x  y checkpoint_name
0  0  0           Alpha
1  0  1           Hotel
2  0  2          Indigo
3  0  3            Papa
```

Output:

```
   x  y  more_cols  Alpha  Hotel  Indigo  Papa
0  0  0        0.0    0.0    1.0     2.0   3.0
1  0  1        0.5    1.0    0.0     1.0   2.0
2  0  2        1.0    2.0    1.0     0.0   1.0
3  0  3        1.5    3.0    2.0     1.0   0.0
4  0  4        2.0    4.0    3.0     2.0   1.0
5  0  5        2.5    5.0    4.0     3.0   2.0
6  0  6        3.0    6.0    5.0     4.0   3.0
7  0  7        3.5    7.0    6.0     5.0   4.0
8  0  8        4.0    8.0    7.0     6.0   5.0
9  0  9        4.5    9.0    8.0     7.0   6.0
```

Comment: It's a nice and elegant solution indeed.